# Who is Greer talking to in Episode 19, Season 2?

Tags: person-of-interest

Towards the end of the *Person of Interest* Season 2 episode “Trojan Horse” (E19), Greer is shown talking to someone on the phone. It sounds like he is making an update to someone else.

[image]

Who is the person on the other end of the phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## We don't know

It's never fully revealed who the other principal leaders of [Decima Technologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Person_of_Interest_(TV_series)#Decima_Technologies) are but Greer is the Director of Operations.

Presumably although he is the primary operative he must still have to report back to his base to update them on his current activities and the state of play.

This would be standard procedure in case he is taken out of play or rendered ineffective by some means.

**Out of Universe**

Having Greer report back is merely exposition and drives the plot forward in a way that is easy to follow and provides additional information to the audience that the characters do not yet have.